# Java SocketException: Connection reset,. What is the cause?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I wrote a simple client-server program. The client connects to the server, then sends a message to the server. The server prints the message. My problem is that I don't understand why I get a SocketException: Connection reset exception when I don't call the sendMessageToServer() method. When I call the method everything works without an exception.

```
public class Client
{
    private Socket socket;

    public  Client(int port) throws IOException
    {
        this.socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), port);
       // sendMessageToServer("Hello Server!\n");
    }

    public void sendMessageToServer(String message) throws IOException
    {
        try (BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));)
        {
            bufferedWriter.write(message);

        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

public class Server
{
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;

    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

    public Server(int port, int backlog, InetAddress inetAddress) throws IOException
    {
            this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port, backlog, inetAddress);
    }

    public void startListening() throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("Listening...");

        while (true)
        {
           ClientHandler clientHandler = new ClientHandler(serverSocket.accept());
           System.out.println("Connected");
           executorService.execute(clientHandler);
           System.out.println("Waiting for another client");
        }
    }

}

public class ClientHandler implements Runnable
{
   private Socket clientSocket;

   public ClientHandler(Socket socket)
   {
       clientSocket = socket;
   }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {

        try (
                // read from client
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        )
        {

            // read message from client
            String message = "";
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                message += line;
            }

            System.out.println("Client message = " + message);


        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

I expected that if I did not call the sendMessageToServer() method then the server would write out an empty message.

Comment: The problem is that you aren’t closing the socket in the client. So when it exits, Windows resets it. If you call your send method it gets closed by the try statement.

Comment: Despite the fact that the Socket directly is not in the try-with resource, if there is a BufferedReader associated with it, the Socket will also be closed correctly?

Comment: That’s what I said. Closing either stream of a socket closes the other stream and the socket.